# Efficient rotation of non-journal logs with systemd?

Tags: systemd

I'm moving a service from ECS on AWS to EC2 and as part of that need to figure out log handling. The service generates about 30GB of logs per day per instance. I'm using systemd to start the service as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Proxy Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /app/proxy-all.jar
Restart=on-failure
User=proxy
StandardOutput=file:/var/log/proxy/output.log
StandardError=file:/var/log/proxy/error.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My issue is how I can do logrotation? If I run logrotate to rotate the logs, then since the server still keeps the file handle open to the old file, it will just keep writing there. Does systemd somehow support logration itself?

One dirty solution would be to restart the service every time after log rotation, but this is a critical service that keeps a over a hundred thousand persistent websocket connections and restarting would kill all connections, so this is not doable.

Forwarding to e.g. rsyslog would be one option, but I would like to minimize the number of components I use to keep things simple, so I can focus on coding and not ops.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on the EC2 instances, which has Systemd version 245.

Answer (score 0):

Systemd does not have a built-in feature to proxy writes to files. Using `StandardOutput=file:***` will always result in the service directly holding open handles to that file, at which point systemd cannot force it to close and re-open the file.

Not counting syslog, one of *two* ways to solve this is to change your service to directly do file logging instead of stdout logging – then it would be fairly easy to build log rotation (close/rename/open) into the service itself, or at least have it react to some external signal and just close/reopen the current file.

The other alternative is to use *external* tools which could be used in a pipeline, which would do the exact same task. (Such a tool would also need to log directly to a file instead of relying on systemd's stdout redirection. Sure, you can close stdout even if it's been redirected, but what path do you use when trying to re-open it?)

There are several such tools, e.g. Apache httpd comes with a [rotatelogs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/rotatelogs.html) tool which is generic enough that it could be used in combination with any service. Another one that I've found is [cronolog](https://github.com/fordmason/cronolog).

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "exec java -jar /app/proxy-all.jar | rotatelogs /var/log/proxy.%Y-%m-%d.log"
StandardOutput=none
```

However, as this now relies on your Java service running as part of a pipeline, it can actually interfere with systemd's keeping track of the "main process", so I wouldn't recommend it – it'll be better to have the service itself log to file.

Comment: I decided to go with rsyslog anyway and forward logs there. The reason is that rewriting the logging system of the application would be too much work at the moment.